# Cannot access deb.debian.org from VM after port forwarding using /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, port-forwarding, qemu

### Setup

On **host** server with Debian Bookworm I created two VM-s (**pserver** 192.168.122.227 and **pagent-1** 192.168.122.126) via cockpit (kvm). Both of them are running Debian Bullseye. I am using default network.

At this point everything works, I can access network from either of them.

Since I cannot use bridge due to only having one IPv4 address I wanted to forward 80 & 443 ports from **host** to **pserver**. So I created `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu` on **host**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Source: https://wiki.libvirt.org/Networking.html#Forwarding_Incoming_Connections

if [ "${1}" = "pserver" ]; then

   GUEST_IP=192.168.122.227

   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:80
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:443
   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:80
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:443
   fi
fi
```

### My problem

After this change SSH to both vms from **host** works, but `sudo apt update` on both **pserver** and **pagent-1** fails, since it cannot reach `deb.debian.org`. On **host** everything works okay.

On **pserver**:

```
sudo apt update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (2a04:4e42:8e::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (146.75.122.132), connection timed out Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:8e::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (2a04:4e42:8e::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (146.75.122.132), connection timed out Cannot initiate the connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:8e::644). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can ping it, but I cannot wget it:

```bash
ping deb.debian.org
PING debian.map.fastlydns.net (146.75.122.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 146.75.122.132 (146.75.122.132): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=5.33 ms
64 bytes from 146.75.122.132 (146.75.122.132): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=5.37 ms
```

```bash
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/
--2023-11-24 10:52:59--  http://deb.debian.org/debian/
Resolving deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)... 146.75.122.132, 2a04:4e42:8e::644
Connecting to deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)|146.75.122.132|:80...
```

And there it gets stuck.

Did I accidentaly make iptables rules too broad or maybe overwrote some iptables rules?

Comment: Please, confirm that you are not using a proxy

Comment: @J.M.Robles I am not. I am almost sure problem is with iptables rules in hooks/qemu, since everything works when I turn off the pserver vm (and subsequently iptable rules in hooks get turned off).

Comment: Your NAT rules don't filter what they will apply to: so they apply to everything. port 80 gets redirected to the VMs: creating a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNAT rules don't filter what they will apply to: so they apply to everything: Internet-initiated traffic as well as VM-initiated traffic. Anything using ports 80 or 443 always get redirected to the VM 192.168.122.227, including traffic from that VM itself or other VMs (host itself is unaffected, this would require a nat/OUTPUT rule). This creates a loop when using HTTP or HTTPS from a VM (but lets ICMP pings work, making diagnostic harder).

The four DNAT rules in the qemu hook script should be amended so they won't affect the VMs (also introducing a parameter for libvirt's bridge name):

```bash
...

GUEST_BRIDGE=virbr0

...
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING ! -i "$GUEST_BRIDGE" -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:80
...
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING ! -i "$GUEST_BRIDGE" -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:443

...

    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -i "$GUEST_BRIDGE" -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:80
...
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -i "$GUEST_BRIDGE" -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:443

...
```

The rule won't apply when traffic is initiated from the bridge, ie from a VM: VM-initiated traffic won't be changed and won't loop back to a VM. The rest of the ruleset should probably be changed to reuse `"$GUEST_BRIDGE"` too.

In case the bridge interface isn't exactly known in advance or is not the default `virbr0` (but is still a bridge for the sake of simplicity), it can be retrieved from the implicit `virsh xmldump` VM's properties provided to the script on *stdin* by (installing and) using [`xmlstarlet`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/xmlstarlet). Replace the `GUEST_BRIDGE` line with:

```bash
GUEST_BRIDGE="$(xmlstarlet select -t -m 'domain/devices/interface' -v 'source/@bridge')"
```

`xmlstartlet`'s usage is a bit complex, but is even used in this [libvirt hook script example](https://wiki.libvirt.org/OVS_and_PVLANS.html#hook-script). What matters is that the VM's properties (in XML format) are provided *only once* to *stdin*. Should other parameters be retrieved, this has to be done in the same shot.